# Webdriver driver.getWindowHandles() only return 1

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

webdriver opened a IE browser A, click a link in "IE browser A" will trigger sso.exe ,and then opened a new IE Browser B.

After B opened,

```
Set set = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

but set.size() is 1, expected 2.

How can I resolve this?
I desperate the solution..
much appreciate~!

Comment: What Selenium and IE versions are you using?

Comment: try to put some wait before `Set set = driver.getWindowHandles();` or put a breakpoint at this line and execute it after you see window fully opened.

Comment: yes, I set wait for 30 seconds, and I am sure the new Browser B have already opened, but the size is 1 expected 2.   @Guy, my env is  : ie8/win7/selenium3.3.4